# How to parse image feed with php

Tags: php, xml, parsing

Using Wikipedia API link to get main image about some world known characters/events.

Example : ([Stanislao Mattei](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&aiprop=url&format=xml&ailimit=1&aifrom=Stanislao%20Mattei))

This would show as following
[image: Wikipedia API Stanislao Mattei]

**Now my question** 
I'd like to parse the xml to get image url to be shown up

here is the code i'm willing to use if it right ~ thanks to [ccKep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1179287/cckep) ~

```
<?PHP
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&aiprop=url&format=xml&ailimit=1&aifrom=Stanislao Mattei";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$extracts = $xml->xpath("/api/query/allimages");

var_dump($extracts);
?>
```

It should gives results as array

how i can get among it the exact url of the image to be shown  should be :

```
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Stanislaus.jpg
```

to put it in html code

```
<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a1/Stanislaus.jpg">
```

~ Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `$xml->query->allimages->img->attributes()->url`

---

Your code will look like this:

```
<?php
ini_set("user_agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");

$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&aiprop=url&format=xml&ailimit=1&aifrom=Stanislao Mattei";

$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$url = $xml->query->allimages->img->attributes()->url;

echo "URL: ".$url . "<br/>";
echo '<img src="'.$url.'">';

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , works perfect and would helps me a lot as study case.